# How to check .AspNet.ApplicationCookie in application

Tags: cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am developing an application in which users login in using different identity providers. Owin middleware create .AspNet.ApplicationCookies. I want to check whether it exist or not and its contains some data in it or not. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

This cookie is encrypted by OWIN and is not easily accessible as a raw cookie data. However you can check if user is logged-in via `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` or just via `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` if you are executing this in controller or a view.

If you put claims (that is the best way to add data into cookie) you can check list of claims for the currently logged user via `((ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).Claims` - this is basically a key-value list of strings. And name of identity provider will be stored there as well.